# How to find the median of 5 elements by rote and its time complexity is O(n)

Tags: algorithms, selection-problem

[image]

In the first step, I agree that divide n elements into groups take one pass so the time complexity is 
$$O(n)$$.

But if we need to find the median of each 5 elements, we may have to sort them. I know the time complexity of sorting is 
$$O(nlogn)$$.

How to find the median of 5 elements by rote and its time complexity is O(n).
I cannot understand "**by rote**"

Comment: "By rote" means "by a stupid/naive method". For instance, you could use any $\Theta(n^2)$ sorting method and pick the middle. Whatever you do, the running-time for each 5-element block will be constant.

Answer (score 0):

"By rote" means "by a stupid/naive method". Here, the simples possible method is to check for each element if it's the median (by checking how many of the others are smaller or larger).

You could use any $\Theta(n^2)$ sorting method and pick the middle element. Or enumerate all permutations of the five elements and search for the sorted permutation.

Whatever you do, the running-time for each 5-element block will be constant, and so the total effort of that step will be linear.

---

You seem to be stuck at some basics of algorithm analysis; please refer to [our reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844) to clear the waters.

Comment: I only partly agree with you. If you use a $\Theta(n^2)$ sorting method  to find the median, you need to find n/5 times. This is not a $\Theta(n)$ algorithm anymore. Why is that..

Comment: @skytree When setting $n \geq 5$, Landau symbols use meaning. *Every* algorithm takes $O(1)$ time if you bound the input size.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase $5$ is a constant, you can use (almost) any naive method to find the median of $5$ elements in constant time.

However, it is known that $6$ comparisons are sufficient (and necessary) to find the median of $5$ elements (try yourself). There are $\lfloor n / 5 \rfloor$ groups of $5$ elements. Hence, the second step can be done in time $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: The analysis is tricky. You divide n elements into groups. For each group, you assume it is constant and finally you conclude that the whole algorithm is constant. So tricky

Comment: @skytree We did not *assume* it is constant. We have proved that it is constant. $6$ is a constant. We did not conclude the second step can be done in constant time. We proved that it is $\Theta(n)$.